# How to load content for Sub Menu in Tabs ( AngularJS + Bootstrap )

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am building a page with TABs with Sub-Menu, as shown in link below I am using ui-router to achieve this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ug4M0YoNyPmmpk4G1jmr?p=preview

Final UI will look like following:

```
Home   Order              Report 
          Step 1             Step 1 
          Step 2             Step 2
```

I can load tabs content but am not able to figure out how to load sub menu content?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: dashboard.html file is missing in you plunker or haven't you have that file in your project. Add that and it will work fine.

Comment: I added same but no difference. http://plnkr.co/edit/wcH7pEYVeOjVIlEu3loX?p=info Sub menu click does not load its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `dashboard.html` file and inside the `dashboard.html` file add `<div ui-view class="ng-scope"></div>` and inside Order.html file add `<div ui-view class="ng-scope"></div>` .

Since you have created three level nesting you should have `ui-view` under each level of the html file

Comment: Works like charm. thanks a lot ! updated http://plnkr.co/edit/ug4M0YoNyPmmpk4G1jmr?p=preview  for reference.

Comment: Welcome.. glad to know it helped.